# Какой треугольник называется чередующимся?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Чередующийся треугольник, то вверх острым углом, то повёрнутый
>   основанием.

Расширенный контекст (мало помогающий):

> Вот справа – если стоять лицом к алтарю – круг хоть и такого же
>   диаметра, как прочие, но отличается по тому оформлению, в котором
>   лежит: это разработанный, чёткий, повторяющийся рисунок. Чередующийся
>   треугольник, то вверх острым углом, то повернутый основанием. Кстати,
>   в некоторых храмах можно обнаружить точь-в-точь треугольник
>   Серпинского, который считается открытием 1915 года. Треугольник в
>   богословии – символ Святой Троицы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Представьте себе паркет, выложенный из одинаковых треугольников. [Вот это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82) имеется в виду. "Чередующийся треугольник" звучит очень плохо, но если поставить во множественном числе, то станет непонятно, что имеются в виду одинаковые треугольники. Всё равно лучше во множественном, я думаю.

Фраза про ковёр Серпинского свидетельствует о непонимании автором "математики", о которой он говорит. Не уверен, насколько это важно для целевой аудитории, но мне это режет слух.

Comment: Гриззличек, к тебе автор стучится: *а можешь уточнить у 

grizzly, как правильно переформулировать свою мысль.* 

(Фраза про ковёр Серпинского свидетельствует о непонимании автором "математики", о которой он говорит. Не уверен, насколько это важно для целевой аудитории, но мне это режет слух.)

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Может я зря придрался. Правильно было бы сказать примерно так: "Кстати, в некоторых храмах можно обнаружить изображение точь-в-точь похожее на треугольник Серпинского, удивительные свойства которого были открыты и изучены лишь в 1915 г." Просто для математика треугольник Серпинского — значительно более сложная вещь, хотя она и похожа внешне на тот рисунок. А открытие было связано именно с этими отличиями / сложностями, а не с тем изображением, которое можно встретить в храмах. Если Вы / автор сочтёте это уточнение не столь важным, тогда примите / передайте мои извинения.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Щас кааак отправлю в Рим!!!

Answer (score 2):

ЧЕРЕДОВАТЬСЯ, -дуюсь, -дуешься; нсв. 1. Последовательно сменяться, по очереди заменяться другим. Печаль и радость чередуются.

Думаю, можно сказать:

**Чередующиеся треугольники: то вверх острым углом, то повернутый (вверх) основанием.**

или

**Чередующиеся положения треугольника: то вверх острым углом, то основанием.**

Answer (score 1):

**Чередующийся треугольник, обращенный вверх то острым углом, то основанием.**

О треугольниках: http://kudes.ru/?q=book/export/html/3071

Comment: По ссылке нет "чередующегося" треугольника.

Comment: Там просто дана символика треугольников, обращенных вершиной вверх и вниз.

Comment: Но у нас вопрос о том, может ли объект быть *чередующимся*. Или все-таки чередуются (сменяются) всегда несколько объектов (напр., гласные в корне)

Comment: Если объект  последовательно меняет свое положение,  то его вполне можно назвать чередующимся, хотя бы условно/образно. Фактически мы имеем два треугольника, сменяющих друг друга.

Comment: Чередоваться могут только две и более сущностей.